# Parsing XML-Like Web Service (web service returns xml within a string)

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I'm trying to parse a "not-so-normal" XML web service.  It appears the web service is returning a string, with XML inside that string.

The XML looks like this:

```
<string>
  <NewDataSet>
    <Table>
      <CATID>0</CATID>
      <DEPID>0</DEPID>
    </Table>
    <Table>
      <CATID>1</CATID>
      <DEPID>1</DEPID>
    </Table>
  </NewDataSet>
<string>
```

This is my code as of right now, I've already tried numerous variations but can't get anything to work.  Most of the time it just returns nothing.  I've echoed $xml and it will return all the XML, but I just need to show the CATID and nothing else.

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('http://theWebSericeLink.here');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);

 //echo $xml;
 foreach($xml->Table as $item) {
   echo $item->CATID;
 }
?>
```

I've also tried:

```
   foreach($xml->NewDataSet->Table as $item)
```

and

```
   foreach($xml->String->NewDataSet->Table as $item)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: last closing tag (string) is written with mistake (without /). Does this mistake exist in source?

Comment: @Will Irvine Are you check my answer

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo.  The source does have the closing tag.

Comment: BTW `simplexml_load_file` would load that XML file (URL) directly btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Before my foreach function, I created an xml file from the "xml string" the web service was returning:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
$feed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>'.$xml;

file_put_contents("workhorse.xml", $feed);
$myxml=simplexml_load_file("workhorse.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$k = '<string>
    <NewDataSet>
        <Table>
          <CATID>0</CATID>
          <DEPID>0</DEPID>
        </Table>
        <Table>
          <CATID>1</CATID>
          <DEPID>0</DEPID>
        </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
</string>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($k);

   foreach($xml->NewDataSet->Table as $read){       
     echo $read->CATID."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Output

```
0
1
```

Comment: This does work in your example, but using the return from my web service it would not.  I'm not sure why, but it just wouldn't work no matter how I tried.  The problem here was the web service I had to use, not you guys. :) I did figure it out though, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the XML when you echo it, then you may need to use xpath.

```
$id = $xml->xpath('/table/CATID');
```

Comment: I tried this and couldn't get it to work.  I did figure it out though, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, close the tag  at the end, and start with "`print_r`" the xml variable.

```
print_r($xml);
```

As there are parents and children tags, It is like an `array` to get a result through each field.

In your case,

```
<string>
   <NewDataSet>
     <Table>
```

So

```
$tables = $xml->NewDataSet->Table;

foreach ($tables as $table)
{
    foreach ($table->CATID as $catid){
        echo $catid, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont parse string.  Error occurred.  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in  on line 16

Comment: I tried this and couldn't get it to work.  I did figure it out though, check out my answer.